# Can I use a string variable to reference a class variable?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Here's the scenario:

I have an external swf file with `x` number of movieclips in its library that I load into a containing swf. Each MC in the external swf is linked with a class name and referenced on frame 1 as such

`var unique1:lineSequence1 = new lineSequence1();`

the `unique1` variable name will match a string variable I create in the containing swf:

```
function initLines():void{
   lineLoader = new Loader();

   lineLoader.load(new URLRequest("theLines.swf")); //load external swf
   lineLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, linesLoaded);  
}

function linesLoaded(e:Event):void{ 
   var loadedswf:MovieClip = e.target.content as MovieClip;

   var initialLines = projects[0].pageid; //projects is an xmllist

   trace("initialLines: "+initialLines); //returns "initialLines: unique1"

   lines_holder_mc.addChild(loadedswf.[initialLines]);
}
```

I would like to use the `initialLines` variable as the reference to `unique1` instead of hardcoding `unique1` into `loadedswf.unique1` to reference said variable in the loaded swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove the dot and use bracket notation like this:

```
lines_holder_mc.addChild(loadedswf[initialLines]);
```